# How to merge videos side by side if one of them is cropped

Tags: ffmpeg, editing

I have 2 videos of the same resolution, but I need to crop one of them and then merging them side by side, so that general height would be equal of height of non cropped video. I.e. they should look the same size after merge. Just cropped video should look like it zoomed in.

I tried to do that, but ***uncropped video being cropped during merge***.
I **cropped** like that:

```
ffmpeg -i L.MOV -filter:v "crop=in_w-28:in_h-28" -c:a copy LC.MOV
```

Then **merge** which crops right video:

```
ffmpeg -i LC.MOV -i R.MOV -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast LCR.MOV
```

Here I drew what I need:
[image]

And here what I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i L.MOV -i R.MOV -filter_complex '[0:v]crop=in_w-28:in_h-28,scale=640:480,setsar=1,pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast LR.MOV
```

Since you want a zoomed-in effect, after cropping, you should rescale it back to 640x480. Your crop dimensions are disproportionate to the input dimensions so I have reset SAR to 1. You can skip this if you apply `crop=in_w-28:in_h-21`.

---

To apply the crop to the right video, use

```
ffmpeg -i L.MOV -i R.MOV -filter_complex '[1:v]crop=in_w-28:in_h-21,scale=640:480[int];[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[left];[left][int]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast LR.MOV
```

Comment: I forgot that height not equals width. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to rewrite command if I would need to crop right one instead of left (I can't figure that out) ?

Comment: Replace first `[0:v]` with `[1:v]` and `[int][1:v]` with `[0:v][int]`

Comment: it crops both videos by half.

Comment: Run command with -report and share report.

Comment: Here is log file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LlTMzD5I2YGVLG3QixTvvIb9rkww5j57

Comment: Malware detected in earlier link.

Comment: Use my new command in answer.

Comment: Malware - I've seen that. It works now - thank you very much.